# How to make html5 <audio> play stream url without path?

Tags: html, url, audio, video

the url like http://stream2.jenny.fm:9000/ or http://188.165.23.150:9700

I tried
code 1:

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://stream2.jenny.fm:9000/" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
```

and code 2:

```html
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/OriginalMusicPlayer.swf" width="225" height="86"> 
   <param name="movie" value="media/OriginalMusicPlayer.swf"/>
   <param name="FlashVars" value="mediaPath=http://stream2.jenny.fm:9000/" /> 
  </object>
```

both don't work.

Why html5  don't accept these url?

Comment: The url is content-type is text/html. pass the mime type of vide in url

Comment: But, just now, I found if I append a semicolon to the url, it will work. like

Comment: http: // stream2.jenny.fm:9000 /;